# Converting [Integer] -> Integer

Tags: list, haskell, integer

I have never programmed before and i have just recently (1 week ago) started learning! The first course is functional programming, using **Haskell.**

I have a school assignment that I'd like to improve by removing one or two steps, but there's one pesky bug in my way.

Basically, I create a list and i get the result with the type `[Integer]`, whereas I'd like to convert this to `Integer`, if possible? I've set my test function to accept the types `Integer -> Integer -> Bool` (takes two values, computes them, and returns a bool). The test function puts the values into two functions and compares their results.

I could just change the expected type to `[Integer]` (?) but that would eliminate the option of manually putting in values.

For my test cases I've chosen a few values and put them into lists. `a = [0, 2, (-3)]` and `b = [0, 2, 4]`. What I'd like to do when I call the function is to enter `a` and `b` as the values, instead of typing in each testcase every time. Is this possible? Example:

```
testFunction a b
```

instead of something like

```
testFunction Integer Integer.
```

I hope I made sense :-) Keep in mind I am just learning!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do.  It seems that you want to pull test values out of two lists to pass to a test function.  Do you want to execute every combination of elements from `a` and `b`, or just pairs of values like `testFunction 0 0`, `testFunction 2 2`, `testFunction (-3) 4`?

Comment: What this sounds like is you want a function `testFunction :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Bool]`, which at each step takes the first elements of each list, runs your function `testFunction` and then appends it to a list of previously calculated versions. See if you can think of a way to phrase that in Haskell.

Comment: are you allowed to use libraries? QuickCheck would help with testing.

Comment: Following up on @C.Quilley's suggestion, how could you do this with recursion?  I'll start you off: `testAll :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Bool]`; `testAll (x:xs) (y:ys) = <something with "testAll xs ys">`; `testAll _ _ = []`, where the last case catches the cases where either or both of the input lists are empty.

Comment: Another hint:  Try typing your desired type signature into [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and seeing what comes up.  I bet within the top 10 suggestions returned you might find something that could help you.

Comment: @bheklilr Sorry if i was a bit unclear, i'm unsure of how to phrase my question haha. English is not my native tounge. :)

Comment: My test function takes two arguments, i'd like it to take the first argument from list a, and the second argument from list b. First element for the first test, second element for the second test and third for the third test. The answers i've gotten gave me some stuff to look up, thanks!

Comment: @Rewbert Then the `zipWith` function that is built in will work for your case, but I would highly recommend trying to implement the recursion yourself, you'll learn a lot in the process.  It's not a very difficult function to implement, either.  Start by implementing `zip` (try it out in GHCi to see what it does), then try implementing `zipWith`.  You'll have to use recursion to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Without making this too complicated for you, what you seem to be looking for is the ability to pass two lists of Integers to a function, which accepts Integers, to perform an element-wise operation.

For this, you can use `zipWith`, which has a type signature of:

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

This type signature means that zipWith takes a function that accepts two individual elements, and two lists and returns a list built upon the results of the function that you passed.

In sum, you would be executing:

```
zipWith myFunction [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8]
```

Now, you want to create a function that first uses `zipWith` on each of your two functions, and then uses `zipWith` yet again to compare the two resulting lists, to finally return the Booleans. If you wanted to be even more sophisticated, you could use the `and` function at the end, to return a single Boolean, if all of the Booleans are `True`.

Now, building that function is left as an exercise to the reader :)

I hope this helps.